# XPC connection interrupted for iOS 9 when in app purchase alert display

Tags: xpc

While Buying the editions,  there is a Sign In dialog for iTune Store.

After signing in or while entering  the credentials app becomes unresponsive and it logs down  **“XPC connection interrupted”**   message.

We tried following solutions and those didn’t not work out 
1. Removed the UIWebView, UITextView from Project 
2. Removed the existing UIImageView  and again added UIImageView

While searching solutions to this issue most of the time we found  solutions for the project that contains storyboard used in it. 
Our project do not use storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. Hope you already found a solution to this. I still wanted to share the solution I found.

I had custom observers in the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` delegate class. When I removed the observers, the error vanished.